# Unable to store twitter responses into SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, twitter, pyodbc

I am trying to harvest data from twitter using the search API into a SQL database with the python package pyodbc.

- I am doing this based on keywords and storing the output in a MS SQL database which I have set up in SQL Server Express 2008

  1. The data should enter the "TweetTemp" table first
  2. Then permanently store into the "TweetBank" table
  3. Finally keep a record in the "TweetLog" table.

My program is able to connect to my database, however no tweets have been harvested. Only keywords and the runID have been returned in my "TweetLog" table.

The rest of the tables are completely null.
The tweets are returned in the python output, but with a unexpected error above each returned tweet

**Error message displayed from a tweet example:**

```
############### Unexpected error: <class 'pyodbc.DataError'> ##################################
        Tweet from @metallicalyrc Date: Tue Dec 30 12:03:04 +0000 2014
         September 27 1986: Cliff Burton dies in bus accident in Sweden. Truly a sad day. His legacy will live on forever.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this, or come across this issue with pyodbc before? I've crawled the web, but no solutions to this error message. It seems that perhaps pyodbc isn't processing the data properly, and therefore its not being pushed to the SQL database properly as I can't see an issue with my sql logic.

**Here is my code:**

```
import string, json, pprint
import urllib
import string, os, sys, subprocess, time

import pyodbc
import twitter

from genericpath import exists
from twitter.archiver import statuses
from collections import Counter
from lib2to3.btm_utils import tokens

CONSUMER_KEY = 'MY KEY'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'MY SECRET'
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'MY OATH TOKEN'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'MUOATH TOKEN SECRET'
auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                           CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)
print twitter_api

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MYSERVERNAME;DATABASE=MYDBNAME;UID=sa;PWD=MYPASSWD')
cur = conn.cursor()
# connect to database and create a cursor to do some work

harvest_list = ['metallica', 'james hetfield', 'lars ulrich', 'kirk hammett', 'rob trujillo', 'jason newsted', 'cliff burton']
# harvest list separated in the database by keyword

cur.execute("select max(isnull(batchid,0)) from tweetlog")
batch_id_cur = cur.fetchall()
# updated 3-8-2012
if batch_id_cur[0][0] is None:
    batch_id = 0
else:
    batch_id = batch_id_cur[0][0]+1
# grabbing the last "batch id", if it exists in order to make log entries that make SOME sense

for tweet_keyword in harvest_list: # for each keyword, do this

    cur.execute("""delete from tweetbanktemp where tweet_keyword = '"""+str(tweet_keyword)+"""'""")
conn.commit()
# whack the temp table in case didn't exit cleanly

search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=tweet_keyword, count =100)
# search for the current keyword

for tweet in search_results['statuses']:
        # some me the tweet, jerry!
        print "        Tweet from @%s Date: %s" % (tweet['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8'),tweet['created_at'])
        print "        ",tweet['text'].encode('utf-8'),"\n"

        try:
                # try to to put each tweet in the temp table for now
                cur.execute("""insert into TweetBankTemp (tweet_id, tweet_datetime, tweet_keyword, tweet, tweeter, lang)
                                         values ('"""+str(tweet['id_str'].encode('utf-8').replace("'","''").replace(';',''))+"""',
                                                 '"""+str(tweet['created_at'].encode('utf-8'))+"""',
                                                 '"""+str(tweet_keyword)+"""',
                                                 '"""+str(tweet['text'].encode('utf-8').replace("'","''").replace(';',''))+"""',
                                                 '"""+str(tweet['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8').replace("'","''").replace(';',''))+"""',
                                                 '"""+str(tweet['metadata']['iso_language_code'].encode('utf-8').replace("'","''").replace(';',''))+"""'
                                         ) """)
        except:
                print "############### Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0], "##################################"
# backup in case something bad happens all the tweets arnt lost

        cur.execute("""insert into tweetbank (tweet_id, tweet_datetime, tweet_keyword, tweet, tweeter, lang)
         select * from tweetbanktemp where tweet_id NOT in
         (select distinct tweet_id from tweetbank)""")
# take all the tweets DIDNT already have and put them in the REAL tweet table

        cur.execute("""delete from tweetbanktemp where tweet_keyword = '"""+str(tweet_keyword)+"""'""")
# take all THESE out of the temp table to not interfere with the next keyword

        cur.execute("""insert into tweetlog (BatchId, keyword, RunDate, HarvestedThisRun, TotalHarvested) values
         (
         '"""+str(batch_id)+"""',
         '"""+str(tweet_keyword)+"""',
         getdate(),
         ((select count(*) from tweetbank where tweet_keyword = '"""+str(tweet_keyword)+"""')-(select top 1 isnull(TotalHarvested,0) from tweetlog where keyword = '"""+str(tweet_keyword)+"""' order by RunDate desc)),
         (select count(*) from tweetbank where tweet_keyword = '"""+str(tweet_keyword)+"""')
         )""")
# add a record to the log table saying what happened

        conn.commit()
        # finish
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use SQL server? If you must use it, why use ancient and problematic ODBC? Wouldn't TDS based be better, eg pymssql?

I suggest switch to pymssql and have a test script that receives a fake tweet from the command line and puts it into the database. (You can have another script to remove all test tweets). Once that is reliable, the rest of your pipeline should be fine.

Comment: Hi Andrew. I have also been trying with pymssql, but I couldn't even get it to connect to my SQL database, hence using pyodbc. Here is the connection string that I tried with varying parameters which was failing: "conn = pymssql.connect(server='MYSERVERNAME', host='localhost', user='sa', password='MYPASSWD', database='MYDBNAME')"

Comment: Without knowing your specific server, I can't help with connection parameters ;)   Are you restricted to using mssql?

Comment: What specific details do you need? In a sense yes. I previously tried with MYSQL and had some datatype errors and couldn't even connect to the server. Using mssql has been the furthest progress I made.

Comment: I have managed to provide the right connection string for pymssql by adding the port number parameter. However the error produced above each tweet returned is now "pymssql.Operational Error"

Answer (score 0):

Is tweet_datetime a DateTime column?
If it is, the issue isn't the connection, it's your SQL

Try printing out the text of the SQL you are sending via ODBC, it probably looks something like this:

```
insert into TweetBankTemp (tweet_id, tweet_datetime, tweet_keyword, tweet, tweeter, lang)
                                     values ('SomeTweetID',
                                             'Tue Dec 30 12:03:04 +0000 2014',
                                             'SomeTweetKeyword',
                                             'September 27 1986: Cliff Burton dies in bus accident in Sweden. Truly a sad day. His legacy will live on forever. ',
                                             '@metallicalyrc',
                                             'en-us'
                                     )
```

If you run that in SSMS you will get a date conversion error. SQL Server has no idea how to convert Tue Dec 30 12:03:04 +0000 2014 to a date.

Try printing the query and seeing if that is the problem. If it is, you'll need to add some logic to convert your date to a format SQL Server understands (I suggest yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss).